# Displaying an image in WebBrowser from a link (fitting the image!)

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, browser

I've a link to an image (it's not a direct link, like "image.png", because I think the image is automatically created).

I managed to download and display the image and it worked, but the pinch-to-zoom and drag it's a bit buggy..

If I open this link in the WebBrowser the drag and zoom are perfect, but I get the entire page (that is blank...). It's like having a white page with a small image on the top left, instead I would like the WebBrowser to wrap the image. I think due to the body width.

I know exactly the dimension of the image, is there a way to fill the WebBrowser with my image?

This is the address to the [image](http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/b?s=USDEUR=X), as you can see there's no .png or .jpg or whatever..
I tried also to give to the WebBrowser an html string like:

```
string html = "<html style=\"width:512px;height:288px;\"><body style=\"height:288px;\"><img src=\"" + source + "\"></body></html>";
```

but it didn't work..

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are passing HTML directly to your browser control.  I haven't had a chance to try this with that particular approach, but what you want to consider is the viewport meta tags.

Try adding this to your `<Head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Awesome! I added this and works great! <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=512, height=288\">